# How to use output of one command as an input to another on VSTS CI

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, azure-devops, build-definition, aws-device-farm

I'm trying to set up CI on Microsoft's *[Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/)* (VSTS) that includes *[AWS CLI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools#user-content-run-aws-cli-commands)* task. I have some steps for building an iOS app and those steps are successfully executed. Then, I want to upload generated `.ipa` files to [AWS Device Farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/) using AWS CLI commands.

To upload files to AWS, I followed [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/create-upload.html), where it is stated that I have to run `aws devicefarm create-upload ...` command first. This command is executed successfully on VSTS and it outputs JSON formatted response, like this:

```
{
    "upload": {
        "arn": "arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:123456789012:upload:070fc3ca-7ec1-4741-9c1f-d3e044efc506/dd72723a-ae9e-4087-09e6-f4cea3599514",
        "name": "MyAppiOSUITests_20180309.3.ipa",
        "created": 1520601466.978,
        "type": "IOS_APP",
        "status": "INITIALIZED",
        "url": "https://prod-us-west-2-uploads.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Adevicefarm%3Aus-west-2%3A123456789012%3Aproject%3A070fc3ca-c7e1-4471-91cf-d3e4efc50604/uploads/arn%3Aaws%3Adevicefarm%3Aus-west-2%3A123456789012%3Aupload%3A070fc3ca-7ec1-4741-9c1f-d3e044efc506/dd72723a-ae9e-4087-09e6-f4cea3599514/app.apk?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20170824T224008Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAEXAMPLEPBUMBC3GA%2F20170824%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=05050370c38894ef5bd09f5d009f36fc8f96fa4bb04e1bba9aca71b8dbe49a0f"
    }
}
```

This basically means that this command just prepares upload and to upload real file, I have to do HTTP PUT afterwards (using `curl` as suggested).

In that JSON response I get `url` object whose value is a URL that I have to send HTTP POST request with the file I want to upload, like this:

```
curl -T MyAppiOSUITests_20180309.3.ipa "https://prod-us-west-2-uploads.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Adevicefarm%3Aus-west-2%3A123456789012%3Aproject%3A070fc3ca-c7e1-4471-91cf-d3e4efc50604/uploads/arn%3Aaws%3Adevicefarm%3Aus-west-2%3A123456789012%3Aupload%3A070fc3ca-7ec1-4741-9c1f-d3e044efc506/dd72723a-ae9e-4087-09e6-f4cea3599514/app.apk?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20170824T224008Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAEXAMPLEPBUMBC3GA%2F20170824%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=05050370c38894ef5bd09f5d009f36fc8f96fa4bb04e1bba9aca71b8dbe49a0f"
```

Problem is that I have to use two tasks (`aws` and `curl`) to upload single file, where the second one depends on the output of the first one. How can I save output between VSTS build tasks (and parse it to get just value of `url` object) and pass that output to another task? Or, can I avoid using `curl` and just use `aws` tool with single command to upload file to Device Farm?

*Note*: I'm using Mac powered agent that is connected to VSTS, so all of these commands are executed on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I'm not overly familiar with VSTS, but I see you're using a mac, so if you want a full BASH implementation you could do something like.

```
var=$(cat file.txt | jq -r '.upload.url')
curl -T TEST.ipa $var
```

Comment: Exactly what I did. I wrote commands in shell scripts and I didn't use `AWS CLI` after all. Extracted data in scripts and made it to run tests on AWS. Also, to send URL argument to `curl`, I have to send it with quotes (just like in documentation), so this `-r` in `jq` command is a surplus. Without it I get object value with quotes.

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t the [output variable](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/blob/master/docs/preview/outputvariable.md) in AWS CLI task, you may submit the issue here: https://github.com/aws/aws-vsts-tools/issues

The workaround is that you can get the task logs through [Build Log REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#logs), so you can call REST API to get the task log (e.g. through curl), then extract data from the log.

Comment: Thanks, good idea to post issue on GitHub. Also, your workaround might work, but I think it's cumbersome to do it like so.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add `echo` to the first script/command, you can pass the value as an environment variable to the second script/command using the `##vso[task.setvariable]value` message. See details at [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md).

Comment: But the question was about how can I add `echo` to first command. How can I do that?